# A biderectional lstm with RNNSharp

Tags: c#, lstm

I am almost new in recurrent neural network. Recurrent neural networks like rnn, lstm, bi-lstm etc. are almost all implemented in python. I want a C# tool of recurrent neural network and found RNNSharp. The inputs of this framework are complex. Is it possible to implement a bidirectional lstm with RNNSharp. If possible, then please help me to create the model with minimal Snippet Code or a link. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The input of RNNSharp is compatible with CRFSharp, which supports templates. In addition, RNNSharp won't get updated for any new feature, you could try Seq2SeqSharp which supports both bi-LSTM and transformer models. It's tensor based and support CPU and multi-GPUs. Here is the link: https://github.com/zhongkaifu/Seq2SeqSharp

You can get input/config examples on that page.